# WSDL to PHP wsHttpBinding support

Tags: php, wsdl

I am using WSDL to PHP service to send request to the API endpoint. I've been using this service for many projects and everything was successful. But now I'm trying to connect to a WCF which supports only wsHttpBinding.

Many experts said SOAP 1.2 may handle wsHttpBinding but I'm unaware of where to configure soap version in WSDLtoPHP app.

Could somebody help me out?